# How to output my value in a div wrapped with an anchor javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to output my value in a div wrapped within a anchor. Basically someone types in the height he wants and it gives him the equivalent datasheet.

I cant work out the way how to output the string I want in the div wrapped in an anchor.

Here is my code:

```
<form name="test">
<label for="height">Height</label>
    <input type="text" name="height" /><br>
    <label for="width">Width</label>
<input type="text" name="width" /><br>
<label for="depth">Depth</label>
<input type="text" name="depth" /><br>
<label for="load">Load</label>
<input type="text" name="load" /><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="calculate();" value="Calculate" /><br><br>



</form>
<div id="result">
</div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                        function calculate()
                        {
                            var height = document.test.height.value;
                            if (height <= 525) {
                                var str = "Download your Datasheet 1";

                            }
                            else if (height < 645) {
                                var str = "Datasheet 2";

                            }

                            else if (height > 1265) {
                                var str = "This configuration is beyond the standard range of top-load testers. Please contact Mecmesin Sales to discuss ways to meet your requirements.";
                            }

                            else if (isNaN(height)) {
                              window.alert(height + ' is not a number!');
                              }

                            else {
                                var str = "Datasheet 3";
                            }
                            document.test.result.value = str.anchor();

                        }
            </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the others have missed the point about making the div contain an anchor ... This would suggest that you will need to provide a url as well as a string, but once you've done that the additional code to replace the *document.test.result.value* line should look something like:

```
// empty out the result div first
var node = document.getElementById('result');
while(node.firstChild) {
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
}

// create the anchor DOM object
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode(str);
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = str;
a.href = "http://example.com/"+str+".pdf"; //for example

// attach it to your result node
node.appendChild(a);
```

If you don't plan on reusing the page without refreshing it, you can do without the while loop.

Comment: Yeah but I could do this could I ?  var str = '<a href="#">Download your Datasheet 1</a>';

Comment: You could, but it's advisable to get used to handling the dom directly. It's much more fun, especially when you get into using frameworks like Dojo ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: Your answer was correct but one beneath explained better :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
var height = document.test.height.value
```

This line is not giving you the value of height in the form.

Give that input an id like 'height' and then get it's value like this:

```
var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
```

You cannot access element as properties of the document object like you are trying to do, you need to select them using something like document.getElementById or document.getElementByTagName

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the DOM correctly.

You need to give an ID to the `height` input:

```
<input type="text" id="height" name="height" />
```

```
var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
```

---

Or you could simply use:

```
var height = document.getElementsByName("height")[0].value;
```

but i wouldn't recommend that.